# What is the difference between Visual Studio Publish Web and the Project Publish Web windows?

Tags: visual-studio, msdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

What is the difference between these 2 windows in a given project in Visual Studio?

Am I correct in assuming that the first pic is the settings of what the project does when it gets published, while the second pic is the dialog to get the Publish profile setup?

You see this one when you right-click the Project settings, and click Properties.

[image: Screen shot of Project Publish settings]

This one you get to from the Menu, Build --> Publish {project name}

[image: Screen shot of Publish Web dialog]

Answer (score 0):

The project dialog represents common deployment options. The publish dialog allows you to configure "Publish Profiles" that publish/package to specific locations.

It's possible to override the common deployment options in your publish profiles' `pubxml` files via `<PropertyGroup>`, but there is no UI for it.